# How to disable an embedded youtube video when clicking on another video on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, video, tabs, embed

I have in my web several tabs where in the content of each one there is an embedded video and when I play the video of tab 1 and I change tab the video keeps playing, I need that when I click on the video of tab 2 the video of tab 1 stops playing.

I have tried to access the video tag in iframe:

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    let iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')
    iframes.forEach(element => {

        if( element.attributes.title.value == 'YouTube video player'){
            let video = element.querySelector('video')
            console.log(element.contentWindow.document.body.getElementsByTagName('video'))
        }
    });
}
```

However I get the following error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin  from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: you can stop and play a youtube video using [youtube player api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).  alternatively, use a js library for video playing. maybe even plyr.js